# MySQL interests table structure (how-to?)

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been figuring my way around MySQL for a while now, reading tutorials and such but I've got a good idea of how things work, so this time around I'd like to see if I can do it myself but I'm a little confused on one part.

I'm trying to create a interests table for users to interact between their interests.
I'm confused on how I'd go about storing the interests information for the users.

**user_interests** *table*:

```
interest_id | interests_names |
```

How could I enter specific interests for them to use without them typing their own into the database such as, sports, life, hobbies, food, music, games, etc.

should I create another column in the user_interests for each user id to be stored in there?

I'm lost on the table structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
  user_id int not null auto_increment primary key, 
  user_name varchar(32)
);
CREATE TABLE interests
(
  interest_id int not null auto_increment primary key, 
  interest_name varchar(32)
);
CREATE TABLE user_interests
(
  user_id int not null, 
  interest_id int not null,
  foreign key (user_id) references users (user_id),
  foreign key (interest_id) references interests (interest_id)
);
```

To list all users and their interests

```
SELECT user_id, interest_name
  FROM user_interests ui JOIN interests i
    ON ui.interest_id = i.interest_id
```

To get list of users who share the same interest in 'sports'

```
SELECT q.user_id, u.user_name
  FROM
(
  SELECT ui.user_id
    FROM user_interests ui JOIN interests i
      ON ui.interest_id = i.interest_id
   GROUP BY user_id
  HAVING MAX(i.interest_name = 'sports') = 1
) q JOIN users u
    ON q.user_id = u.user_id
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/80ce8/5)** demo

Comment: @iBrazilian Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?

Answer (score 0):

Create another table called standardInterests or similar, and plug that into a listbox in your application, as the data source for them to select interests from.